# Сохранение потока на телефон

Tags: android

1. Есть аудиопоток типа site.ru/radio.mp3.
2. Есть две кнопки "Старт" и "Стоп".

Как сделать чтобы при нажатии на кнопку старт началось сохранение/запись потока в телефон, а когда нажимаешь стоп чтобы останавливалась запись/сохранение.

Готовых решений не нашла я что-то может быть тут подскажут как реализовать или примеры скинут?

Comment: В англоязычной версии stackoverflow есть ответ на похожий вопрос, возможно Вам это подойдет: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17732190/how-to-record-and-save-as-mp3-online-streaming-audio